# $4^n - 1$ in base $2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would you answer this question. Write $4^n - 1$ in base $2$. Given the context of the question I assume that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I'm  fine with converting regular numbers to and from different bases but I don't know what a sufficient answer to this question would be. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: By hand you should be able to work out the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$; with luck you might be able then to guess the answer for $n=3$ and maybe also higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$4^n-1=2^{2n}-1$, which is just $2n$ 1's in binary

Comment: Thanks guys I knew that the answer was a string of 2n 1s  from doing exactly this but just was blanking on how to express this as an appropriate answer. All your answers help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: I did adjust the answer to make clear what occurs in cases where n is negative but its pretty much the same just with a decimal point to show that its the fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

$4 = 2^2$,
So $4^n-1 = (33333\ldots n~times)_4 = (11~11~11~11~11\ldots 2n~times)_2$.

Just replace each digit by its binary equivalent. $(3)_4 = (11)_2$

Answer (score 0):

$4^n - 1 = 2^{2n} - 1$.

Do I need to remind you that $2^M - 1 = 1 + 2 + 4 + ...... + 2^{M-1}$?

In any event $2^{2n} = 1\underbrace{000....000_2}_{\text{ with }2n\text{ zeros}}$ and $1\underbrace{000....000_2}_{\text{ with }2n\text{ zeros}}-1 = \underbrace{1111...111_2}_{2n \text{ ones}}$.

Comment: "Do I need to remind you" comes on a little strong.  Tone it down a little.

Comment: ""Do I need to remind you" comes on a little strong."  It does?  Why?  It's a legitimate question.